bla is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt on github actions only
I have monorepo, that works locally just fine, but when it runs on CI, it shows weird error something like this:
go: inconsistent vendoring in /__w/x/apps/foo-agent:
    github.com/go-faker/faker/v4@v4.4.1: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt

I checked multiple times, there's no faker import in go.mod or anywhere in the source code tree
go mod why github.com/go-faker/faker/v4
# github.com/go-faker/faker/v4
(main module does not need package github.com/go-faker/faker/v4)

also tried go get ./..., go mod tidy, go mod vendor, but nothing in source code tree changed.
the command being run is:
CGO_ENABLED=1 go test -v -race -coverprofile=./coverage.out `go list ./... | grep "foo-agent" | grep -v /test | tr "\n" " "`


Apparently this is specific on the CI workflow, I forgot to add on github CI, that's why it keep running branch's old code
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

on this section on my workflow:
  unit-tests:
    if: ${{ true }}
    runs-on: "self-hosted"
    needs: build
    steps:

